# React Dynamic menu items passed down via router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Another react question here, I have a solution for my problem but to me it doesn't seem very "React" so I was hoping for another solution.

I'm using react router so the bottom of my app.js(entry point) is:

```
ReactDOM.render(

  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Login} ></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="searches" component={searches}></Route>
      <Route path="notifications" component={notifications}></Route>
    </Route>
   </Router>
  , app);
```

Now as you can see my overarching component is Layout so, in my mind I want to configure my (reusable) components, for example I want my Layout to pass the title of the menu items to the header component, and then if I'm for example loading a search then I might want to pass functions etc to the search component to hook into it's functionality, so I have the following in layout:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();


  }


    render() {
      const containerStyle = {
        paddingRight: '5px'

      }

      // Figure out which props we want based on location.pathname
      const {pathname} = this.props.location;

      switch(pathname){
        case "/searches":
         // So now I need to add some props, functions or anything else to this component
          theProps = {someProp: "value"}
          const theComponent = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {theProps})
          break;
      }
    return (

      < div style={containerStyle} class="container">
        < Header menuItems={this.getMenuItemsForScreen()}/ >
        { theComponent}

        < Footer / >
      < /div>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically in order to pass props from my overarching Layout I have to clone the component and then give it some more props?? It just feels a bit dirty but I can't seem to find a way of embedding this type of logic otherwise?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the great thing about these routing components is that they save you from those ugly switches in your components.

I'm not sure which kind of props you want to send to the searches component. In your question is not clear what is the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of using one of the standard approaches in the react-router documentation.

I recommend considering these alternatives:

1. Refactor your `searches` component to avoid receiving any props. Try to have each route to have a component that doesn't receive any props. So you move that code that define the props (`theProps = {someProp: "value"}`) inside the `searches` component. Or if you need the `searches` component to be reused with those props and other props in another time, then make a new parent component that defines those props and calls the `searches` component then. But if those props are to complex and dependent on your app state then maybe you can consider using *flux*, *redux* or *another state container*, and get those from the app state.
2. If you really need the routing parameters, then make sure the props can be serialized so they can be part of the URL. Check the `message` route in the code below (copied from [RouteConfiguration sample](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)):

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import { render } from 'react-dom'
   import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

   const App = React.createClass({
     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <h1>App</h1>
           <ul>
             <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
             <li><Link to="/inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
           </ul>
           {this.props.children}
         </div>
       )
     }
   })

   const About = React.createClass({
     render() {
       return <h3>About</h3>
     }
   })

   const Inbox = React.createClass({
     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <h2>Inbox</h2>
           {this.props.children || "Welcome to your Inbox"}
         </div>
       )
     }
   })

   const Message = React.createClass({
     render() {
       return <h3>Message {this.props.params.id}</h3>
     }
   })

   render((
     <Router>
       <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="about" component={About} />
         <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
           <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
         </Route>
       </Route>
     </Router>
   ), document.body)
   ```

   In this case your code will have `<a href={"/inbox/message/"+id} ...>` somewhere in your code and those will provide the props by setting the id parameter in this case.

Comment: My god this was two years ago and I missed your answer, I-am-very-sorry!

Answer (score 1):

you use functional component in child component with this code :

```
<Route path="/:id" component={Child} />


function Child({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>ID:{match.params.id}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```